# iOS app only works when installed through xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

I have an app, that install and runs fine, when being installed on device, through xcode.

I can archive the project just fine without any warnings or errors, but when i try to install the .ipa file through itunes, my app starts fine, but then the screen is just black.
The app is using the camera, and for me, without any good experience with this iOS developing, i would say, it feels like the camera is not turning on.

Comment: How do you "install the .ipa file through iTunes"? Is your device "rooted"?

Comment: Do you have a developer account? Did you sign the app when you archived it?